# Iterate through repeater table after sorting results

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm using an ASP Repeater to build an HTML table with data from a database and using the jQuery sortable function so I can drag rows up and down in the table to change their order, this all works fine.

However, once I've changed the order of rows, I want to iterate through them and get the value of the ID field row-by-row.

If I iterate through the repeater, the ID's are still in the order they were when it was loaded (before I dragged rows around) and I understand why that is. How can I iterate through the table and get the rows in the order they are now displayed on the page?

I'm using VB.NET

```html
<table style="width: 100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
                <thead class="text-primary">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="no-padding h5 heavy">ID:</th>
                        <th class="no-padding h5 heavy">Name:</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptResults" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr class="text-primary" style="width: 200px;">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="rowid" runat="server" Text='<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("rowid").ToString())%>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="no-padding h5">
                                    <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString())%>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Are you iterating on Client Side or the server side?

Comment: Changes made by Jquery are not send to the server, so the data will remain in it's original position. You will have to send the new sequence of ID's to the server yourself with a HiddenField or Ajax.

Comment: Am trying to iterate server-side, but could do client if that's my only option, just not sure how?